# How to return multiple values from array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have a asignment i need to finish in few days and i'm stuck on one function.

I need to pull data from array and show 10-20 database inputs from array
This is my function to get values in array:

```
function getRegionInfo(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ".TBL_REGIONS."";
    $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $dbarray = $stmt->fetch();  

    $result = count($dbarray);
    if(!$dbarray || $result < 1){
        return NULL;
    }

    return $dbarray;
}
```

and i pull the array with this

```
echo $database->regioninfo['name'];
echo $database->regioninfo['domain'];
echo $database->regioninfo['language'];
```

Everything is ok with this script but the only problem is now i can pull just one database input from array. What do i need to change in my script to be able to pull more info, i/e if I want to make a list of all array outputs.

Comment: what do you mean database inputs?

Comment: I recommend you start with reading a tutorial how to use the database. Tutorials do exist, also the PHP Manual is a good start.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you should change `$dbarray = $stmt->fetch();` to `$dbarray = $stmt->fetchAll();`.  Calling `fetch()` returns just the first result.

You'll need to iterate through the results once you have them:

```
foreach ($dbarray as $regioninfo) {
    echo $regioninfo['name'];
    // and so on.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the returned data fetching one row at a time and either processing or building an array of the results.